# I'm getting multiple RequestVerificationToken being generated at once

Tags: .net, iis, cookies, session-cookies, verification

When publishing a site to another remote location I am getting multiple RequestVerificationToken generated, the normal one but also one with a number generated afterwards. this doesn't happen on our other installs.

Is there anything on the setup in IIS that could be generating this? I'm unsure of where it could be coming from.[image]

Comment: As far as I know, IIS will not genreate the anti forgery token (prevent CSRF attack) by default. Normally, the anti forgery token is generated by your application. I suggest you could try to use remote debug to debug your generated  anti forgery token codes to make sure it is not firede twice. Details about how to remote debug the IIS application, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019).